# MobaXterm 3270 emulator plugin

Tags: plugins, mobaxterm, mainframe

I'm trying to install the X3270Suite plugin for MobaXterm. I've downloaded X3270Suite.mxt3 and placed it in the same directory as the MobaXterm executable, as per [this link](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html).

However, I can't find a "3270 session" option after restarting the MobaXterm. What am I missing?